# ASP.net Ajax and Page Events

Tags: asp.net, ajax

During Asynchronous postback (Ajax) will Page_PreInt() ,Page_Init(),Page_Load() events fire again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the update panel, then yes, a full page lifecycle will be triggered.  For a more lightweight technique, you could look at using something like jQuery to send AJAX requests to a web service.